# Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Using cloud functions I want the delete certain documents at midnight(I am using pubsub). How can I delete the docs after I queried them.

```
export const taskDeletion = functions.pubsub.schedule('0 0 * * *')
    .onRun((context) => {

        const query = db.collection('tasks')
            .where('dailyTask', '==', false)
            .where('completed', '==', true);

        const tasks = query.get();
        
    });
```

Comment: Don't forget to take timezone into consideration!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use references to the docs and delete them.

```
// using an async function
const tasks = await query.get();

const del_ops = tasks.docs.map(doc => doc.ref.delete())
await Promise.all(del_ops)
//continue
```